# Have a <div> fixed at a height only when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this sidebar:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <h4 style="color: #404040; font-weight: bold;">
            Guides:
        </h4>
        <div class="sidebar">
             <!--auto-generated <ul>...-->
        </div>
</div>
```

And I want it to follow the user as he scrolls down. I know that you can do it with `position: fixed;` in the styles. But I have a header, so if the div is fixed it remains in that height even if I scroll down.

[image: unscrolled]

But if I scroll down, it remains at that fixed point. Here's how it looks like when I scroll down it would look like this:

[image: scroll down]

I want it to remain at the top. I read that I'm supposed to use javascript scroll functions, but I have no clue how, exactly.

Comment: Do you want something like this ?
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: I think you're looking for `sticky` element. Doesn't have good browser support, but I think `position: sticky;` does what you want. And if you're using bootstrap, I think bootstrap affix or scrollspy does this, but I haven't used it. If you want help writing your JS, what do you mean by *"But I have a header, so if the div is fixed it remains in that height even if I scroll down."* Are you saying you want the menu to stay at the top of the section it's in until you scroll to that section, then the menu scrolls with the user until you reach the end of the section, then it stops scrolling?

Comment: @MichaelCoker basically, yes... because the problem with `position: fixed` is that it's fixed in that height

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks, the `position: sticky;` style worked wonderfully, and i didn't have to bother with additional javascript codes

Comment: @user253938 oh nice, I'll submit as an answer then. it's a great solution, but won't work for a lot of folks because of browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky` for an easy "sticky" element. It's a new property, so it doesn't have the best browser support, but easy to use and works well.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .row {
      height: 200vh;
    }
    .row:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
    .sticky-column {
      position: sticky;
      top: 1em;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      scroll down
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 sticky-column">
      <h4 style="color: #404040; font-weight: bold;">
            Guides: (look it's sticky!)
        </h4>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <!--auto-generated <ul>...-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using position: fixed; in style as well as margin-top: -30px; or what ever amount away from top you want:
something like this

```
    <body> 
<div class="sidebar" onscroll="dynamicheight()">
</div>

<script>
function dynamicheight() {
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
var y = sidebar.scrollTop;
document.getElementById('random').style.height = y;
}
</script>
```

Comment: but, then it will overlap with the header

Comment: @user253938 Not if you change the -30px; to something else thats just below the header or use javascript to add a if function that will say if position overlaps header then position below header else position fixed and static top

Comment: no, and i tried what you suggested using `$(window).scroll(function(){});` but i've found out via `console.log()` testing it by adding 1 to `x` each time i scroll down and subtracting 1 whenever i scroll up, that it's not really consistent... so it's not a viable option to change the CSS value each time i scroll

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    var yOffset = $("#sidebar").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > yOffset) {
    $("#sidebar").css({
        'top': 0,
        'position': 'fixed'
    });
} else {
    $("#sidebar").css({
        'top': yOffset + 'px',
        'position': 'absolute'
    });
   }
});
```

Try this too

```
    position:sticky;
```